# How can I parse JSON object in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, xcode, json

I need to parse the data I receive the following way:

```
[
  {
     "IdEmpleado":1, 
     "Nombre":"Cesar",
     "Edad":"25",
     "Genero":"M",
     "IdArea":1
  },
  {
     "IdEmpleado":2,
     "Nombre":"Luis",
     "Edad":"30",
     "Genero":"M",
     "IdArea":2
  }
]
```

I need to get the data for each employee, in the example are 2 employees need all the fields of each object and then turn them into employees.

I already use the JSON and transfer to an NSDICTIONARY, but how I can do to have it structured so each field and being able to pass a Method to convert an object EMPLOYEE?

Comment: You need to be clearer about what you need. Are you trying to automatically create an object that exposes named properties, etc for the structured dictionary ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://stig.github.com/json-framework/

Comment: I already use the JSON and transfer to a NSDICTIONARY, but how I can do to have it structured so each field and being able to pass a Method to convert an object EMPLOYEE?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the JSONFramework, which you can find here.

https://github.com/stig/json-framework/

Comment: I already use the JSON and transfer to a NSDICTIONARY, but how I can do to have it structured so each field and being able to pass a Method to convert an object EMPLOYEE?

Answer (score 1):

```
     NSString *userid= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"Userid"];
        NSString *appurl =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"your link"];
        appurl = [appurl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:appurl]];
        NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse: nil error: nil ];
        NSString  *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSMutableDictionary *deletdict=[returnString JSONValue];
        if([[deletdict objectForKey:@"success"] isEqualToString:@"False"])
        {
            NSLog(@"Unsuccess...");

        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"success...");
        }



AND Post method is this 

    NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"AgencyId=STM&UserId=1&Type=1&Date=%@&Time=%@&Coords=%@&Image=h32979`7~U@)01123737373773&SeverityLevel=2",strDateLocal,strDateTime,dict];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://174.94.153.48:7778/TransitApi/IncidentConfirm/"]]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    NSError *error;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSMutableArray *SubLiveArray=[str JSONValue];


download Json framework on this link:::

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-json-twitter-api


NSString *appurl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=23.041230,72.514346&radius=50000&types=%@&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyAQZ16VzshxGbYdiM8C2RhhwGl3QwVJTB4",_txt_search.text];
```